# What is the default background color of any Page in Xamarin Forms Android?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the default background color in Xamarin Forms Android App in the light mode without applying any custom theme or style? I want to place a button that has the same color as that of the background. The Background color is not White, as when I place Button with White color, the Button's color is different from the background.

I know I can set both Page's and Button's color as White or anything else, but I want to use the same default background color that's provided by Xamarin Forms Android.

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Button" BackgroundColor="White" />
</StackLayout>
```

In the output, you can see the white color of the button is slightly different from that of the background.

**Here is the output**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your theme's default background color in android project by referencing:

```
?android:colorBackground
```

For example,you could open the `Resources/values/colors`,and arbitrarily define a color value

```
<color name="defaultcolor">?android:colorBackground</color>
```

And then you can see that its color value is

```
#fffafafa
```